# Server doesn't read message from client

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, network-programming

I'm trying to implement a simple multi-threaded client/server program: the client sends the server a number and the server creates a thread that sends back the number+1.

The problem is as follows:
The client connects to the server with no problems;
The thread is (as far as i can tell) created without issues; But after the client writes the number in the socket, the server simply doesn't see it. The call to read() gives no errors, it just sits there, waiting forever.

I tried sending more than one integer through it; no difference.
A suspicion i have is that the file descriptor server-side is passed incorectly to the thread,but i can't figure out how. Another suspicion i have is that i am missing something stupidly obvious.

Either way, help is appreciated. 
Any ideas?

Server-side: the loop that creates threads.

```
    while (1) {

    int client;

    printf("[server]Waiting at port %d...\n", PORT);
    fflush(stdout);

    int length = sizeof(from);
    if (client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &length) < 0) {
        perror("[server]Error: accept().");
        continue;
    }

    pthread_t th_id;
    pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, &treat, &client);

    }
```

Server-side: thread's treat function (the problem is here).

```
void* treat(void* client)
{

printf("[thread]Waiting for message...\n");
fflush(stdout);
pthread_detach(pthread_self());

int client_sd = *((int*)client);

int nr;
if (read(client_sd, &nr, sizeof(int))) {
    perror("[thread]Error: read().");
    exit(-1);
}
// The program won't reach this point.
printf("[thread]Read: %d", nr);
fflush(stdout);

close(*((int*)client));
return (NULL);

}
```

Client-side:

```
      if (connect (sd, (struct sockaddr *) &server,sizeof (struct sockaddr)) == -1)
    {
      perror ("[client]Error: connect().\n");
      return errno;
    }

  printf ("[client]Write a number: ");
  fflush (stdout);

  scanf("%d",&nr);

  printf("[client] Read %d\n",nr);

  if (write (sd,&nr,sizeof(int)) <= 0)
    {
      perror ("[client]Error: write()\n");
      return errno;
    }

    //the program reaches here.
  printf("[client]The message was sent\n");
```

Comment: This: 'pthread_create(&th_id, NULL, &treat, &client);' can fail if two clients connect 'simultaneusly'. - 'client' gets overwritten by the accept() thread before the cient<>server threads can read it, but it doesn't seem like it's you main problem ATM.

Comment: It's not my main problem, but it's a problem; thanks for pointing it out. I'll look into it after I fix this one.

Comment: I can't see the problem:(  The read() call should return and something should get printed.  It may not be what you expect because you fail to handle the result returned by read() correctly, but somethng should get printed:(

Comment: @MartinJames can you please elaborate on the secondary issue you mentioned? What would a solution look like?

I thought of making a copy of client and passing the refference to that, but in the next loop it can overwrite that copy just as well. 
As far as i know the thread's function can only recieve a pointer as parameter, so how do I fix this?

Comment: I'm guessing that declaring a fresh pointer inside the loop, asigning `client` to it and passing that to the thread fix the issue? Then on the next loop there's nothing left to overwrite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is at line

```
if (client = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &length) < 0) {
```

it is interpreted as

```
if (client = (accept(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&from, &length) < 0)) {
```

and if `accept` returns positive then the `client` is set to `0`. Subsequent read in the thread is read from stdin then.

Comment: Nice - have an upboat!  I should have spotted that, especally as I am always moaning about devs. failing to split up compound expressions while debugging.

Comment: Also, this is not the first time I've seen this error.  It does not seem 'natural' to me to use the erroneous expression.  I would have put the 'client=accept()' on a separate line as a matter of course.  I suspect that there is, (yet again), some rubbish website with this bad code as an example:(